# VxWorks boot hang (starting at 0x100000)

Tags: vxworks

I'm trying to boot VxWorks 6.3 on a Wind River SBC83XX PowerQUICC II Pro. I'm using Wind River Workbench as my IDE. I configured the kernel, built it, and attempted to run it, but it hangs on `Starting at 0x100000` with no further output.

Here is the output of the terminal after typing `@` at the prompt:

```
boot device          : mottsec
unit number          : 0 
processor number     : 0 
host name            : XXXXXXXXXXX
file name            : C:\WindRiver\workspace\vxworks-dev\default\vxWorks
inet on ethernet (e) : 69.88.163.22:ffffff00
host inet (h)        : 69.88.163.21
gateway inet (g)     : 69.88.163.1
user (u)             : XXXXXXXXX
ftp password (pw)    : XXXXXXXX
flags (f)            : 0x0 

Attaching interface lo0... done
Attached IPv4 interface to mottsec unit 0
Loading... 1838288
Starting at 0x100000...
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated; I need this working for a college class on a tight schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Many things could be wrong.
The first thing I would do is check the RAM size. If it exceed the amount on the board, this might happen.

Is the serial port & shell configured?  I would suggest adding the standalone shell bundle.

Comment: The RAM size seems to be correct, and I believe that the serial port and shell are configured. Where exactly is this standalone shell bundle? Google isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the symbol table is compiled as standalone, this can sometimes occur based on other configurations.

Compile the symbol table into the image.

In Work Bench:
Kernel Configuration -> CTRL+F, search "built-in symbol table", -> include it.